# Cannot load page with either WebClient or HttpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net, webclient

Regardless of whether I use `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`, loading this page times out.  What am I doing wrong?  It can't be `https`, since other `https` sites load just fine.

Below is my latest attempt, which adds all headers that I see in Firefox's inspector.

One interesting behavior is that I cannot monitor this with Fiddler, because everything works properly when Fiddler is running.

```
    Using client As WebClient = New WebClient()
        client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Accept) = "text/html, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, */*;q=0.1"
        client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent) = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; de; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12"
        client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage) = "en-US;en;q=0.5"
        client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding) = "gzip, deflate, br"
        client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Referer) = "http://www.torontohydro.com/sites/electricsystem/Pages/foryourhome.aspx"
        client.Headers("DNT") = "1"
        client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive) = "keep-alive"
        client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Upgrade) = "1"
        client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl) = "max-age=0"

        Dim x = New Uri("https://css.torontohydro.com/")
        Dim data as string = client.DownloadString(x)
    End Using
```

All of this is excess code.  Boiling it down to just a couple of lines causes the same hang.

```
    Using client as WebClient = New WebClient()
        Dim data as string = client.DownloadString("https://css.torontohydro.com")
    End Using
```

And this is the `HttpWebRequest` code, in a nutshell, which also hangs getting the response.

```
        Dim getRequest As HttpWebRequest = CreateWebRequest("https://css.torontohydro.com/")
        getRequest.CachePolicy = New Cache.RequestCachePolicy(Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache)

        Using webResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(getRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            'no need for any more code, since the above line is where things hang
```

Comment: Why apologize for VB.Net code?

Comment: Are you just wanting the pages html?

Comment: Sorry, was trying to make a bad joke.  I have a few pages to read off the site, but can't even get through the first one.  Seems to be specific to the site.  I get the same timeout whether I set all those headers or just use the last 2 lines.  Or if I use an `HttpWebRequest` with a `GET` method.

Comment: I got it to load with a RESTClient addon in Firefox. Are you just getting a timeout then, and no other specific error code? Have you tried putting this in a `try .. catch ..` block, and logging the error?

Comment: It's a timeout exception in a general `try/catch` block.  I can't get any of the .NET methods to load the page.

Comment: Would it help if I added the `HttpWebRequest` code that doesn't work to my original post?

Answer (score 0):

So this ended up being due to the project still being in .NET 3.5.  .NET was trying to load the site, being `https`, using SSL.  Adding this line fixed the problem:

```
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 3072
```

I had to use `3072` since 3.5 does not contain a definition for `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`.